# DigiCert Wizard No certificate availble Win 10

Tags: signtool

I'm trying to use DigiCert Gui to sign an EXE and a DLL. The certificate was available to the previews User Account but the PC was moved to a different location and different Working Group and that user is gone.
When I click the "Select from Store..." button in the gui I receive "No certificate availble" [error](https://ibb.co/n0Efqk).
In the Google research I found it should be managed by mmc. The question is where in mmc I should put the certificate for it to be available? 
[mmc](https://ibb.co/gwB4GQ)

I know what the certificate should be, but I don't know where it should be.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it was very simple - just needed to double click on the cert file and follow the wizard.